# Updating data without redirecting to an update template

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django and trying to make a to-do app. I want to be able to change the status of a task from 'active' to 'finish' without redirecting the user to a different page just to update the status of a task.

i've been reading the docs for the UpdateView class to see if there was a method that allow me to update the value of the status directly but couldn't find anything.

Comment: it needs to use JavaScript (and AJAX to send data to server). Django doesn't have special function for this. You have to learn JavaScript.

Comment: What about redirecting to the same page?